# What is the best way to start a new project from an existing bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repo with a project template that I use to begin new projects, and I'm not sure the best way to duplicate it and start new projects.

Currently I'm manually duplicating the files locally, and removing the git folder.
Then setting up a new repo in bitbucket, and pushing the new duplicate files up from my local.

Should I be forking/cloning/branching? Im not sure...

The new project would never need to be merged with the template as the template repo will remain as a sort of blank canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone source, and then make changes off of that. (aka forking)

The semantics behind branching imply that those changes will eventually become part of the master project. If you're using something as a template, you probably want it to be separate from the repo it came from.